# Config dictionary for unity via XML

Tags: xml, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

How can I configure a dictionary via XML with Unity container?
This works:

```
<register type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,int]" >
<constructor>
    <param name="capacity">
    <value value="10" />
    </param>
</constructor>
</register>
```

But I need ability to add elements in XML config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there are several problems with the configuration you have posted:

1. It appears you are trying to [register an instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#config_instances) rather than [register a type mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#config_registerelement). To do this you need to use the **instance** element rather than the **register** element.
2. The syntax you are using to specify a generic type is not correct. To specify a **Dictionary<string, int>** the proper syntax should be:

   type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib]], mscorlib"

Note the `2 designates the generic type as having two type parameters.

1. [Specifying a value for your instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#config_instances) is achieved by setting the **value** attribute. This is a string value that must somehow be converted into a series of key value pairs for your dictionary. This will not happen by default unfortunately. You will need to write a custom converter which will accept a string and create your key/value pairs. An example of such a converter can be found [here](http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/230927?ProjectName=unity).

As a final note (and a personal preference), I'm really not a fan of using Unity for this type of object creation. I generally use a custom configuration file for any non-trivial initialization settings and use Unity strictly to register type mappings for dependency injection.

Comment: Unity's XML configuration supports a shorthand notation for generics. The `Dictionary[string,int]` syntax is valid for a Unity configuration.

Answer (score 6):

Last time I tried to do that I had to use a custom converter and invent my own parser for dictionary values. I don't remember which research got me there, but here is the registration and the corresponding converter class.

```
<type type="IRequestPolicy" mapTo="RequestPolicyCatalog, Assembly">
   <constructor>
     <param name="dictionary" type="System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.Int32,System.String][], mscorlib">
       <array>
         <value value="1, 'unauthorized'" typeConverter="Assembly.IntStringKeyValueConverter, fore.Core"/>
         <value value="2, 'activation'" typeConverter="Assembly.IntStringKeyValueConverter, Quofore.Core"/>
         <value value="3, 'routing'" typeConverter="Assembly.IntStringKeyValueConverter, Quofore.Core"/>
       </array>
     </param>
   </constructor>
</type>
```

```cs
public class IntStringKeyValueConverter : System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter {
    public override object ConvertTo(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType) {
        return this.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);           
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) {
        return destinationType == typeof(KeyValuePair<int, string>);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value) {
        var comma = ((string)value).IndexOf(',');
        if(comma < 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid string, must contain ',' between values");
        var number = int.Parse(((string)value).Substring(0, comma));
        var str = ((string)value).Substring(comma).Trim(new[] { ',', '\'', ' ' });

        return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(number, str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it myself, but probably you can register a bunch of instances of KeyValuePair class, and then reference them in array used as an IDictionary constructor parameter.